# Execute index of a folder if exists, if not execute php file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want this example URL:

```
example.com/folder/phpfile
```

To redirect to:

```
example.com/folder/phpfile.php
```

It works perfectly, but I also want to be able to execute the `index.php` file of any folder just by this URL

```
http://example.com/folder
```

or

```
http://example.com/folder/
```

or maybe

```
example.com/folder/subfolder
```

But I don't know how, I'm using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}`, as I understand this is a condition to know if the requested file name is either a file or a folder. But I can't make it work.

This is my current `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_])$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Try to change `Options -Indexes` to `Options +Indexes`.

Answer (score 1):

You can meet your requirement using this code in root .htaccess:

```
# by default load index.php from a path
DirectoryIndex index.php
# make sure trailing slash is present for directories
DirectorySlash On

RewriteEngine On

# load /dir/file.php if request is for /dir/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

here is one more thing that we can do to further clean our URLs, i.e., hiding the entry script index.php in the URL. This requires us to configure the Web server as well as the urlManager application component.

We first need to configure the Web server so that a URL without the entry script can still be handled by the entry script. For Apache HTTP server, this can be done by turning on the URL rewriting engine and specifying some rewriting rules. We can create the file /wwwroot/blog/.htaccess with the following content. Note that the same content can also be put in the Apache configuration file within the Directory element for /wwwroot/blog.

RewriteEngine on

```
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php

RewriteRule . index.php
```

We then configure the showScriptName property of the urlManager component to be false.

Now if we call `$this->createUrl('post/read',array('id'=>100))`, we would obtain the URL `/post/100`. More importantly, this URL can be properly recognized by our Web application.

Comment: Please explain what the differences are between those PHP versions, and what the different rewrite targets achieve in this regard.

Comment: _“The index.php appears in your URLs because it is the file responsible for processing all requests to the system”_ – how can you make that statement, without even knowing what kind of system the OP is using? You are also mentioning ExpressionEngine, but I can see no indicator at all in the original question that the OP was using that …

Comment: @CBroe It was an example

Comment: Giving an “example” that is very specific to a certain system being used, without knowing if that is even the case, makes little sense. And neither does making references to that system’s “control panel” – if the OP is _not_ using ExpressionEngine, then your answer is most likely worthless to them.